# CSS won't render on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm trying to see why our CSS won't render on IE. I'm thinking maybe it is something to do with linking the stylesheet? This is hosted on Salesforce Marketing Cloud if it matters. I've included everything in the header below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"><link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="contents/ui/theme/i/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href=""><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="them-style-css" href="https://xx.com/b2c-general-css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" id="g-font-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A300%2C500%2C700&amp;ver=4.9.8" type="text/css"  media="all">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%%=CloudPagesURL(XX)=%%"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%%=CloudPagesURL(XX)=%%"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you click on the link to your CSS file, do you see the styles?

Comment: Please include any console errors present to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: yep, should I be looking for something in the CSS instead?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing with the debugger in IE, but it looks like there is an error here: a.querySelectorAll("*,:x")

Comment: Try to use [F12 developer Network tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/network) to check whether the CSS reference (CSS link) load success, and use the [Elements panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/elements) to check html and CSS style. From the error it seems there is some JavaScript error, try to set [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/debugger) to check it.

Comment: I don't see any errors, jut a few warnings, mainly around invalid html5 doctype

Comment: Have you ever solved the problem? If not, can you post enough code or create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I havent solved it yet. I think the best I can do is share an old version of a similar page (new version has SSL cert): http://cloud.e2.cgma.org/test6

Comment: Hi @ZhiLv-MSFT did including the webpage help?

Answer (score 0):

use the meta in head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Is there anything else to add beyond this? I added to the header and nothing happened, unfortunately.

Comment: In some features of the CSS, an -ms- should be added before it